# Silverlight - Image URI From Application Root

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have many Images like this in my various views:

```
<Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="../../Img/TemplateImgs/Icon_299a.png"></Image>
```

Is there any way to tell SL to load the image from the root of the app—something like `Source="/Img/Foo.png"`

I know I could bind to a URI from my ViewModel, and use the Uri constructor to achieve this, but I'd really prefer something simpler.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would want to do something like 
Source="/COMPONENTNAME;component/Img/TemplateImgs/Icon_299a.png"

Comment: So COMPONENTNAME would be the name of my silverlight project?

Comment: Yes that's what it should be.

Comment: Never really tested it - I was really dropping off Silverlight when I posted the question.  I'll accept the answer for you :)